# ClojureScript Re-frame subscription dereferencing dilemma

Tags: clojurescript, dereference, reagent, re-frame

What's the best of following approaches?

**Outer subscription, early deref**

```
(defn component [msg]
    [:p msg]))

(let [msg (rf/subscribe [:msg])]
    [component @msg]
```

**Outer subscription, late deref**

```
(defn component [msg]
    [:p @msg]))

(let [msg (rf/subscribe [:msg])]
    [component msg]
```

**Inner subscription, early deref**

```
(defn component []
   (let [msg @(rf/subscribe [:msg])]
      [:p msg])))
```

**Inner subscription, late deref**

```
(defn component []
   (let [msg (rf/subscribe [:msg])]
      [:p @msg])))
```

When I keep the inner component pure using outer subscription, I can end up with many arguments that need to be passed through deeply nested structure of often unrelated parents. That can easily become a mess.

When I subscribe inside inner component, it becomes impure, losing easy testability.

Also, I wonder if there is an important difference between early and late  dereferencing, other than I have to pass `reagent/atom` when testing the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll the answer, as always, is "it depends", but ...

**Outer subscription, early deref** leads to pure/testable inners. So that could be a good choice when that's important to you. But we don't use this style much.

**Outer subscription, late deref**  we've actively moved away from this style because it produced code which we later found hard-to-understand.  BTW, if ever we do pass ratoms/cursors/subscriptions around, we like to put a trailing `*` on the argument name to make it clear they are a reference-y thing, and not a value.

**Inner subscription, early deref**  is probably the most used, I'd guess. Feels very natural after a while. Perhaps use `<sub` [from LIN](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/docs/SubscriptionsCleanup.md#lambdaisland-naming--lin)

**Inner subscription, late deref** this works too, but I tend to prefer the variation directly above.  There's always a nagging worry that you might forget to add `@` at the point of use, and that can be an annoying bug to find.

Comment: Thank you for reaffirming my intuition :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this solves your dilemma, but since Re-frame 0.9 you can write `@(rf/subscribe [:msg])` wherever you need a value from the subscription. Subscriptions are cached, so creating many using the same path doesn't yield more than one subscription.
More information in this blog article: https://lambdaisland.com/blog/11-02-2017-re-frame-form-1-subscriptions and [this Re-frame issue](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/issues/218).